# Flutter setSystemUIOverlayStyle is not executed at startup

Tags: flutter, dart

I changed in my "setSystemUIOverlayStyle" the color of the status bar at the bottom.
This is by default white. I want it in black. This works but I see an error and I don't know where it came from?

Why when I click on my application, at launch, the bar becomes white again for a short time? How to avoid this?

**This is the result :**
I run the app and it launches an initialization page with a loader.
Before arriving on the loader, the status bar appears white

[image]

**Main.dart:**

```
void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    setupLocatorService();
    runApp(AppScreen());
  }, (dynamic error, dynamic stack) {
    //print(error);
    //print(stack);
  });
}
```

**My appScreen:**

```
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
    ]);

    // Status bar color
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black
    ));

  
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Notifier>(
      create: (_) => Notifier(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: AppConfig.APPLICATION_NAME,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: AppTheme().data,
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.HOME,
        onGenerateRoute: RoutesClass.generate,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT : I edit the main, but it's the same result:**

```
void main() {
  // Je bloque mon application en verticale
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  ]);

  // Colors de la status bar
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black
  ));

  runZonedGuarded(() {
    setupLocatorService();
    runApp(AppScreen());
  }, (dynamic error, dynamic stack) {
    //print(error);
    //print(stack);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `SystemChrome` methods in build. Put it in `main()` before calling `runApp()`

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white
  ));

  runApp(...)
```

Comment: @xenos92 Where do you exactly put it? Try on the  first line inside main.

Comment: This is what I do, I update the code above

Comment: @xenos92 don't you call `SystemChrome` anywhere else? Or there might be a package you use that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed some strange things when I used `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle`. And I decided to use `AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>` widget to set style of status bar.

Comment: I tried this too, the status bar turns black after the page loads. Like in my video example.
I have the impression that it is the native behavior that does not change. Let me explain, when you launch the application there is a native part that starts with a blank page, then the first page is loaded. This blank page effect does not appear in my example because I changed the start color in the android files. Is there the same solution for the status bar?